# In Web API, the usual convention is to omit "{action}"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I read it in this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#route-templates):

> "{action}" provides the name of the action. In Web API, the usual convention is to omit "{action}".

But I think `{action}` is useful, by using `routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",` in `WebApiConfig.ca`,

I can call the method in controller by url like `http://localhost:1111/controllerName/MethodName`

Why does the doc says *`usual convention is to omit "{action}"`* ?

Comment: The docs says that in the context of [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) where every action you need to do on your ressource pass through HTTP Method and not by calling method (action) on that ressource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes {action} is useful, if we use methods in controller.

In the default template of Microsoft Web-api controller they use direct methods for response from controllers. So dont need to use {action} and if need to use methods in controller then need to implement {action} in routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"

in the Microsoft documentation parameter are optional but methods is not optional. if we use methods then need to integrate in route params.

Answer (score 1):

In my oppion,when you write restful webapi,you should use HTTP Method(GET、POST、PUT、DELETE .etc) and describe your URI after careful consideration.
Can you tell the diffence of URIS as follows:

```
POST http://localhost/users
POST http://localhost/users/addUsers
```

or

```
GET http://localhost/users/1
GET http://localhost/users/findUser?id=1
```

We can see the first one emphasize on the expression of resources,and the second one pay more attention to action.

So if your webapi should follows restful architecture,perhaps you should omit action.Anyway,if not,using template as "/controller/action" is also a good way.